# Magento - Create order from backend

Tags: magento

I'm creating alot of special offers for my customers, which I need to be able to send from inside magento. This is already possible by creating the order from the backend/sales. But the customers will only get an order confirmation and not be able to pay for the order they recieved in their mail.

Is there any module that would make customers able to pay pending orders from their login?
Can't seem to find any? Surely I'm not the only person creating an order with special prices for some customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Advanced Point of Sale module we use for taking phone orders. It isn't perfect but is far better than trying to use the back end.

There is also a plug in for alternative payment method to allow your phone person to handle payment on the back end. We've got that one, too.

And then there is True Order Edit, which we consider essential / requirement for running an online business.